# Euler phi function and powers of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

For small values of  n$\ge$1  it appears that one has the inequality

$\phi(2^n)$ $\le$ $\phi(2^n + 1)$.

However, it seems unlikely that this would hold for all n .

Question:  Are there any explicit values of n known for 
              which the inequality is violated ?

Thanks

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unboundedness of $\omega$ should be easy, but is that enough?  What if the prime factors are so sparse that $\prod_{p \mid 2^n+1} (1-p^{-1})$ is still bounded away from $0$?

Comment: @ErickWong: I got it, we may take the first prime numbers of the form $8k+3$, all of them being a divisor of some $2^n+1$.

Comment: As a bonus fact $2^{25}+1=33554433 = 3\cdot 11\cdot 251 \cdot 4051$ came as a surprise pattern number.

Answer (score 7):

Mark Bennet inspired me, so thanks in advance and a (+1) as a tribute.

We may collect a large number of primes of the form $8k+3$, say $p_1,\ldots,p_N$.

$\frac{p_k-1}{2}$ is odd and by quadratic reciprocity, $\left(\frac{2}{p_k}\right)=-1$, so if we take:
$$ n=\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{p_k-1}{2}\tag{1} $$
we have:
$$ 2^n+1 \equiv \left(2^{\frac{p_k-1}{2}}\right)^d+1 \equiv (-1)^d+1\equiv 0\pmod{p_k}\tag{2}$$
and every $p_k$ divides $2^n+1$. Since
$$ \sum_{p\equiv 3\pmod{8}}\frac{1}{p}\tag{3} $$
is a divergent series,
$$ \prod_{p\equiv 3\pmod{8}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = 0,\tag{4} $$
so the inequality fails for infinitely many $n$s.

Thanks to [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews), we also have an explicit counter-example:
$$\prod_{\substack{p\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{\!\!8}\\p\leq 467}}\!\!\frac{p-1}{2}=118,036,297,108,708,732,142,419,220,832,488,800,078,125.$$

[Mark Bennet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2906/mark-bennet) gives a way smaller counter-example:
$$ n=3^4⋅5^2⋅7⋅11⋅13⋅17⋅23⋅29⋅41⋅53=49,945,180,460,175.$$

Comment: I will note that you can similarly use a large number of primes of the form $8k+5$, instead setting $n = 2\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{p_k-1}{4}$.

Comment: Beat me to it, but here is a specific value:$$\prod_{p\equiv 3\pmod 8; p\leq 467} \frac{p-1}{2} = 118,036,297,108,708,732,142,419,220,832,488,800,078,125$$

Comment: Actually, you can just take the LCM of those $\frac{p-1}{2}$, to get a smaller value: $$n=90,403,558,182,154,471,186,807,875$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I just mentioned your result. Probably by putting together your idea (LCM) and Rolf Hoyer's one we may also get a reasonably small counter-example.

Comment: But we could find the order or $2$ in each of the primes, and then take the least common multiple of those orders. This yields the slightly smaller: $$n=18,080,711,636,430,894,237,361,575$$ This is just 1/5 of the prior value.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The thing to note is that examples using primes $8k+5$ don't mix with examples using primes $8k+3$.  In the former case, you can only have $p\mid 2^n$ for odd values of $n$ (for instance $43\mid 2^n$ when $n = 7\mod 14$) and in the latter case you have $p \mid 2^{n}$ for values of $n$ that are twice an odd value.  For instance $5\mid 2^n$ exactly when $n = 2 \mod 4$ and $41 \mid 2^n$ when $n = 10 \mod 20$.

Comment: @RolfHoyer Ah, I see. In any event, this doesn't give a smaller value, because the edge of starting $\prod \frac{p-1}{p}$ with the term $\frac{2}{3}$ versus $\frac{4}{5}$ is huge. To get $$\prod_{\substack{p\equiv 5\pmod 8\\p\leq N}}\frac{p-1}{p}<\frac{2}{3}$$ you have to choose $N=101$. And then it takes a huge number of additional terms to get to $\frac12$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I went to bed where I'd left off, and was thinking some of these thoughts - it's good to see them worked out.

Comment: Note: the point of my computations was to take primes of small order rather than just small primes. Then look at the orders to reduce the number and value of prime factors involved in computing the lcm of orders. I've used primes up to abut $2000$ and haven't proved my computations optimal. There are some primes not of form $8n+3$ which appear in the list - $281, 617$

Comment: Yes. Please don't post lists that are not spaced with spaces, or you break comment formatting. Please delete your prior comments and reformat them. @MarkBennet

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Apologies. I hope that my revised comment is now OK. I deleted the previous one as it was suboptimal anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it's an easy mistake to make here - StackExchange comments have been known to get into a state even where the "edit/delete" button isn't clickable, because it is to the right and "underneath" the links, which requires a moderator to fix.

Comment: I think this is the best I can do (I hope it is now checked and formatted correctly) $3^4⋅5^2⋅7⋅11⋅13⋅17⋅23⋅29⋅41⋅53=49,945,180,460,175$ with the primes being 3, 11, 19, 43, 59, 67, 83, 107, 131, 139, 163, 211, 251, 281, 307, 331, 379, 419, 443, 523, 547, 571, 617, 691,‌ 739, 811, 859, 1051, 1123, 1171, 1451, 1531, 1723, 2003

Comment: I got the same value using a greedy algorithm. @MarkBennet

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that if I am careful about counting larger primes which are implicit factors, I can gain enough from those to lose the factor $53$!

Answer (score 2):

For each prime factor $p|2^n+1$ you get a reduction of $\frac {p-1}P$ in the $\varphi$ function. The $p$ you are looking for are ones for which $2^n\equiv -1 \bmod p$. Then for odd $k$, $2^{kn}\equiv -1 \bmod p$. So if we work with odd exponents we can collect primes - the question is can we collect enough small primes.

Now we have $2^1\equiv -1\bmod 3, 2^5\equiv -1 \bmod 11, 2^7\equiv -1 \bmod 43$ and the list of powers and primes continues $(1:3), (5:11), (7:43), (9:19), (11:683), (13:2731), (15:331)$ - for these the relevant factor is approximately $0.5581$ and we need it below $0.5$

No doubt someone can search more efficiently than I can to provide a definitive conclusion.